# Reference required to assembly 'System.Data.Common', containing the type 'DBConnection'

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm making a program in VB with MySQL. For some reason, I got an error where all of my references had a yellow triangle, but I have since fixed that by reinstalling them on NuGet. Now I have 39 errors which I didn't have before, and I haven't edited the code since then.

Here are the errors:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw6US.png)

That isn't all of the errors, but the rest are a lot of duplicates. Now here's my form1 code.

```
Imports MaterialSkin
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Data


Public Class Form1

Private Sub LoginBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginBtn.Click
    Dim address As String
    address = "http://ipv4bot.whatismyipaddress.com"
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim reply As String = client.DownloadString(address)
    Dim connString As String = "Database=aquarius;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=asd"
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
    Dim Query As String
    Dim Query2 As String
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        conn.Open()

        Query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = ?UserName AND password = ?Password AND buyer = ?Buyer"
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?UserName", MaterialSingleLineTextField1.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?Password", MaterialSingleLineTextField2.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?Buyer", "true"))
        cmd.Connection = conn
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If reader.HasRows() Then
            conn.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Thanks for buying Aquarius", "Welcome")
            conn.Open()
            Query2 = "INSERT INTO logs (ip, user, time) VALUES (?Ip, ?User, ?Time)"
            Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand(Query2, conn)
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?Ip", reply.ToString))
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?User", Environment.UserName))
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?Time", System.DateTime.Now.ToString()))
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()

            Form2.Show()
            Me.Close()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Your password is incorrect or you are not whitelisted.", "Sad")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error")
    End Try

End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim SkinManager As MaterialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance
    SkinManager.AddFormToManage(Me)
    SkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.DARK
    SkinManager.ColorScheme = New ColorScheme(Primary.LightBlue500, Primary.LightBlue600, Primary.LightBlue700, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.WHITE)
End Sub

Private Sub MaterialRaisedButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MaterialRaisedButton1.Click

    Dim connString As String = "Database=aquarius;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=asd"
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
    Dim Query As String
    Try
        conn.Open()

        Query = "INSERT INTO login (username, password, buyer) VALUES  (?UserName, ?Password, ?Buyer)"
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?UserName", MaterialSingleLineTextField1.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?Password", MaterialSingleLineTextField2.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?Buyer", "false"))
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Done!", ":)")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should connect your VB program to a API that insert's into a database. Somebody with a disassembler can get the database connection details from your program.

Comment: Could you share your whole project? Looks like you missed a right assembly or you use different framework that assembly need

Comment: Im using .Net 4.5.2

Comment: The error message in the title says that you're missing a reference. Have you checked to see whether that library is referenced and, if not, referenced it?